# How to UV unwrap a circle?

Tags: mesh, uv

I am modeling an alarm clock and they say to go to mesh UV unwrap then unwrap in my face for the clock. I have to giant circles I just want one.

Comment: please try to [edit] your question so that it is clearer what is going on. A picture of your object and the UV layout would be a good start.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to be understood. Could you be more specific, add a image or 2 to describe where you are stuck or even better attach the file you are working on so that others could look at the file directly ... you can upload the file using this link... http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

1: Are you following the  “Blender for beginners: Alarm clock 1 of 2” tutorial.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay7fgeQC1WI   ?

2: When UV unwrapping the clock face at 11:40 are you saying that you have two circles showing up in the UV space instead of one big one?

Two circles unwrapped instead of one means that you have two circles selected in the 3D edit window before unwrapping.

You need to go back to the 3D edit window and check out why two circles were selected instead of only one.

Perhaps you have the the glass lens selected instead of the clock face?

If you still don't see how two circles are being selected then I suggest you add your .blend file to your post

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

then someone can take a look at it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I can show you how it's done at least how I prefer it, if I was unwrapping a clock.

1. Create a circle object.
2. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode
3. Select the face you want to unwrap ... in this case the circular face.
4. Switch your view to top view if your clock face is facing Z axis ...
5. Or switch to left or right side view if your clock face is facing X or Y axis.
6. Hit <kbd>U</kbd> and select "Project from View"

You should now have that face unwrapped nicely into the square texture Grid space.